# Unexpected input error when doing subtraction in R

Tags: r, rstudio

i try to run:

```
x = (1 / 1 – 2)
```

And here is the message:

```
Error: unexpected input in "x=(1  / 1 �"
```

I have the same issue with these sign : <- and * and minus, none of them are recognised.

Comment: Check the symbol  `−`. You may have copied from some text and replace it with `-`

Comment: you saved my life

Comment: Don't copy/paste code in/out of programs (Word?) that have auto-correcting features. Your dashes and quotes will often be replaced, rendering the code invalid.

Comment: I see there are some closing votes for "simple typographic error" motive, i don't agree and the resolution might in the contrary be 'useful to help future users" imo (which is the criteria). But maybe the title should be changed to "unexpected input error after pasting a simple arithmetic operation"

Answer (score 1):

You might be confronted to the so-called "zero-width space" which is not interpreted as a space. Check this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space):

If the blanks you have in your code example are this kind of character, it will make an error like this:

```
Error: unexpected input in "x=(1 / 1"
```

as some comments point out, one must be careful when pasting code from websites.

Comment: The error suggests that the dash is the problem, not the spaces.

Comment: @agenis You could update the post with the actual error dash